# How can I print the value of a variable, either env or arg, at "docker build" time?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Title says it all.  The ARG instruction prints the variable and it's *default* value, not it's current value.  I'd like to know it's current value.

How do I find that?

I mean, I know what was passed in, but that's apparently not what's being used so I'm confused.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just `echo` it?

If you take this Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG test
RUN echo $test
```

and build it with

```
docker build --build-arg test=hello . --progress=plain
```

it prints `hello`.

Comment: Echo happens at docker run time, doesn't it?  I'm looking for something that happens at docker build time.

Comment: No. It happens at build time. RUN statements happen at build time. CMD and ENTRYPOINT happen at runtime.

Comment: That's my cognitive mismatch, then.  I'll try that.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it: When running `docker build` I do NOT see the value "echo"d in build steps. Where can I even see the "echo"d value?

Comment: @goulashsoup After Docker switched to using BuildKit by default, the output from the build command has changed. I've updated the command in my answer to support BuildKit.

Comment: In my case it didn't work because ARG was defined too high. When I moved it lower near echo, it worked

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @HansKilian is probably the way to go if you are able to change the Dockerfile **and** check the value of the build-arg on build time.

Otherwise, here is another way to know **after the image build time** what were the values of the build args: the only requirement is that after the `ARG` directive you are interested in, there is at least one `RUN` directive (but not necessarily using the build-arg `$variable`). − If it's not the case anyway, this `ARG` directive wouldn't be useful at all!

#### Proof-of-concept

Consider the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG test1
RUN echo any shell command
ARG test2
RUN echo another shell command
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

You can build this example image like this:

```sh
$ docker build --build-arg test1="hi" --build-arg test2="hello world" -t image-name .
```

then run:

```
$ docker history image-name --format {{.CreatedBy}} --no-trunc
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]
|2 test1=hi test2=hello world /bin/sh -c echo another shell command
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG test2
|1 test1=hi /bin/sh -c echo any shell command
/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG test1
[…]
```

to get from the *history* of the image (displayed in reverse chronological order), the concrete values of the build args (cf. `|2 test1=hi test2=hello world` …). These build-args values are specifically exposed as *environment variables* at build time, hence this notation with `=` signs here, and the `|2` prefix denotes the number of variables assignments that have to be extracted from the displayed command line.

Comment: The "proof of concept" thing at the beginning was a little confusing, but the `docker history` command is totally what I needed, ty.